# C++ CLI System.String^ to MFC LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, string, mfc, c++-cli, lpcstr

How would I convert a System (.net) `C++\CLI` `String^` into a MFC C++ `LPCTSTR` string.

It is very easy to get a `LPCTSTR` into `String^`, but so far found nothing on doing it the other way around.

Comment: note that LPCTSTR is just a char pointer, so maybe you'd rather convert String to CString or std::string and then obtain the pointer so you don't have to deal with memory managment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2008 or above, you should be able to do this using the C++/CLI marshaling library, like so:

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;

...

String^ cliString;
marshal_context context;

LPCTSTR cstr = context.marshal_as<const TCHAR*>(cliString);
```

More information on marshaling between types on MSDN: [Overview of Marshaling in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx)

Comment: Why not use LPCTSTR tstr = context.marshal_as< const TCHAR* >( cliString) and let the build environment take care of the actual string type?

Comment: I've taken you up on your sensible idea, which for some reason had slipped my mind. Thanks!

Comment: What's the difference between this marshal compared to the marshal in the other answer?

Comment: Besides better semantics, using `marshal_context` means that the allocated string is destroyed when the context is destroyed. Calling `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAuto`, on the other hand, requires you to `FreeHGlobal` the returned string.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try [Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobaluni.aspx), [Marshal::StringToHGlobalAuto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalauto.aspx) or [Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx).

Remember the allocated unmanaged strings will need to be freed with [Marshal::FreeHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx).