# Symlink Windows

Tags: window, c++-cli, symlink

I'm trying to create a Symlink Generator with c++/cli ( Windows based )
There is a Docu on Microsoft ( [MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866(v=vs.85).aspx) )

But i dont know excactly how it works.

I tryed to find a working excample, but i could not find one and i could not get a working solution on my own.

My Complete Code [HERE!](http://pastebin.com/qMEN0xAr)

```
private: System::Void btnCreateSymlinks_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
  String^ pathSource = GetSourcePath();
  String^ pathDest = GetDestinationPath();
  String^ folder = System::IO::Path::GetFileName(pathSource);
  lblInfo->Text = pathSource + " -> " + pathDest + "" + folder;
}
```

How do i use the CreateSymbolicLink function with those pathSource and pathDest?

Comment: This [article](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/24/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Creating-symbolic-links-with-C_2300_.aspx) might help.

Comment: its for c# and i need c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use .NET strings on the garbage collected stack, you'll need pinning pointers (this is something that p/invoke does automatically for C# coders, but C++/CLI coders need to request).

```
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wcsTarget = PtrToStringChars(pathSource);
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wcsSymlink = PtrToStringChars(Path::Combine(pathDest, folder));
```

Then just call the Unicode version of the API (since .NET strings are always Unicode).

```
CreateSymbolicLinkW(wcsSymlink, wcsTarget, 0U);
```

Comment: PtrToStringChars is not working with pin_ptr<wchar_t> 
at least for me i dont know

Comment: i tryed a workaround with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782669/c-cli-system-string-to-mfc-lpctstr bit CreateSymbolicLinkW is not working

Comment: @xQp: Stay far away from MFC, and no reason to translate from Unicode to ANSI here, since the symlink API would just need to translate it back.  If you don't have `#include<vcclr.h>` add it and try `PtrToStringChars` again.

Comment: Please explain "does not work".  Is there a compile error?

Comment: It says: "_const_Char_ptr PtrToStringChars(_const_String_handle s)
get ean interior gc pointer to the first character contained in a System::String object

Error: A value of typ ""_const_Char_ptr"" can not be used to initialize an entity from Type ""cli::pin_ptr<wchar_t>""

Comment: @xQp: Sorry, forgot `const` in my example code.  Please see my edit.

Comment: now its working
but i made a mistake, it has not the same effect as MKLINK /d :/

Comment: @xQp: Your question specifically passes a **filename**, not a directory.  To make it work with directories, use the `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY` flag as the third parameter.  The documentation you linked explains that.

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) u r awesome